# Makefile for Latex: Build only files that have changed

Tags: makefile, latex

I have the following Makefile in order to build some separated TeX files to PDF:

```
# Makefile:

TEXS = $(wildcard *.tex)
PDFS = $(patsubst %.tex,%.pdf, $(TEXS))

all: $(PDFS)

%.pdf: %.tex
    TEXINPUTS=.:../common//: pdflatex -output-directory=../build $< > /dev/null
    rm ../build/*.aux ../build/*.log

clean:
    rm ../build/*.pdf
```

However, the makefile builds always everything. How should I write it such that it just builds the TeX-files that have been changed?

Comment: Instead of running pdflatex, you could use `latexmk`, this will then run pdflatex if necessary (of course you would need to stop deleting necessary auxiliary files)

Comment: The `wildcard` gathers `.tex` file names from the current directory, while the use of `TEXINPUTS` indicate multiple locations.  Do you need multiple dirs for all `.pdf` or the current dir only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU make compares the modification time of the target with the modification time of the prerequisites.

This requires that make know what the path to the target file is.  With this you find all the .tex files:

```
TEXS = $(wildcard *.tex)
```

Suppose there is only one, `foo.tex`.  Then this will convert that to a PDF:

```
PDFS = $(patsubst %.tex,%.pdf, $(TEXS))
```

Now `PDFS` contains `foo.pdf`.  Now you define an implicit rule that says, "if you want to build a `%.pdf` and you have a `%.tex`, here's a way to do it":

```
%.pdf: %.tex
        TEXINPUTS=.:../common//: pdflatex -output-directory=../build $< > /dev/null
        rm ../build/*.aux ../build/*.log
```

All great.

With one major problem: this recipe does *NOT* build `foo.pdf`, it builds `../build/foo.pdf`.  So the next time make runs, and compares the file `foo.pdf` to the file `foo.tex`, it sees that `foo.pdf` does not exist and so it needs to be built and it runs your recipe... which builds `../build/foo.pdf`.  So the next time make runs, ... etc.

If your rule says to make "I will update file X", then it better update that file and not some completely different file.  You want to write that rule like this:

```
../build/%.pdf: %.tex
        TEXINPUTS=.:../common//: pdflatex -output-directory=$(@D) $< > /dev/null
        rm ../build/*.aux ../build/*.log
```

But, now you'll get an error because this rule:

```
all: $(PDFS)
```

asks to build `foo.pdf` and you don't have a rule to build `foo.pdf`, you have a rule to build `../build/foo.pdf` which is not the same thing.  So you have to change your assignment of `PDFS` to contain the directory:

```
PDFS = $(patsubst %.tex,../build/%.pdf, $(TEXS))
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice and detailed explanation!